# MVC5 Cookie authentication using OWIN gets stuck in loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am trying to get basic cookie authentication working in MVC 5, I successfully call signin with the following code. However the Login gets called in a loop unitl I get error "This webpage has a redirect loop".

I cannot see what is failing here, it looks simply like the cookie is not being set?

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Teeko"),
                    },
                                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                                    ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

            // if you want roles, just add as many as you want here (for loop maybe?)
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "guest"));
            //var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            //var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
```

Comment: Do you set a 401 status to the response anywhere? A 401 may be redirected by the auth middlewares which can result in this loop.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. All I do is call signin and the redirect to the returnurl